# Value of type 'MGLMapView?' has no member 'clusterManager' when setting up ClusterKit

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I am working on a `Mapbox` map and want to use the clustering feature found [here](https://github.com/hulab/ClusterKit/wiki/Mapbox). So I copied the code and need to know insert my data instead of the example one.

```
let algorithm = CKNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm()  
mapView1.clusterManager.algorithm = algorithm  
mapView1.clusterManager.annotations = annotations
```

I was setting up the functionality and import the `ClusterKit` and yet mapView1 does not seem to have the `.clusterManager` functionality it is supposed to have. **What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.clusterManager` property [comes](https://github.com/hulab/ClusterKit/blob/master/ClusterKit/Core/CKMap.h#L39) from `CKMap` protocol.

From the documentation:

> /**
>    The CKMap protocol is used to provide cluster instructions and get informations from a map. To use this protocol, you adopt it in any custom objects that represent a map.
>    @discussion An object that adopts this protocol must implement all methods and properties.
>    */
>   @protocol CKMap

Make sure your `mapView1` object as of the type that adopts `CKMap` protocol.
Probably you forgot to set a custom `MGLMapView` class for map view in the storyboard.

And also please make sure your `Podfile` has this line:

```
pod 'ClusterKit/Mapbox', :path => '../.'
```

After that try to update your import code line like this:

```
import ClusterKit.Mapbox
```

Comment: What should be the path?

Comment: It should work "as-is", like it does in their example project.

Comment: I get No such module 'ClusterKit.Mapbox' despite doing pod 'ClusterKit/Mapbox', :path => '../.'

Comment: Please try again just "import ClusterKit" then..., also it might be helpful to clean up the project and try to re-build it again.

Comment: Ya I keep doing that and I keep reruning and changing pods and such and it yeilds the same result evry time

Comment: I belive I found teh problem in that the pod i added had a typo

Comment: Congratulations :)